# How to disable "Copied to Clipboard" toast after copying a sentence programmatically using kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, clipboard

So I provide a user a button that copy a list of paragraph after they have clicked a button, so they won't need to select the paragraph themselves and waste so much effort.

After they have copied using the button, a toast with a text "your paragraph for chapter xx has been copied" will show up

All is well, but the problem is, there is "copied to clipboard" toast comes out as well after the "your paragraph for chapter xx has been copied" toast disappear. It feels like double information, which looks redundant.

is there anyway to disable the "copied to clipboard" toast programmatically?

Below is my copy button's code:

```
val clipboard = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
                applicationContext,
                ClipboardManager::class.java
            )
            val clip =
                ClipData.newPlainText("label", "${chapter_number.text}")
            clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Your paragraph for chapter ${chapter_number.text()} has been copied.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Avoid duplicate notifications](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/copy-paste#duplicate-notifications) might help you to understand the recommended way to notify users about the copied text using `ClipboardManager` API.

Comment: Specifically Jay's link is saying don't notify on Android 13+, because there's a standard system notification when the clipboard is accessed. So you should do an API version check, and only post the Toast for version *32* and below

Answer (score 0):

To disable the "Copied to Clipboard" toast, you can set the duration of the Toast to 0. This will prevent the toast from showing.

```
val clipboard = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
                applicationContext,
                ClipboardManager::class.java
            )
            val clip =
                ClipData.newPlainText("label", "${chapter_number.text}")
            clipboard?.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Your paragraph for chapter ${chapter_number.text()} has been copied.",
                0 // set duration to 0
            ).show()
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it -- the toast will still be shown. In reality, `0` is just an alias for [Toast.LENGTH_SHORT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#LENGTH_SHORT).